# ReactJS смена CSS в зависимости от страницы

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Впервые работаю с ReactJS и возник вопрос: Как динамически сменять CSS-файл в зависимости от страницы?

К примеру, у меня есть файл: `main.css` и `about.css`.
Требуется при переходе на страницу `/` подружать `main.css`, а на `/about` - `about.css`.

Я в файлах `Main.js` и в `About.js` импортирую css-файлы и при выборе страницы, у меня выводятся все css-файлы (`main.css` + `about.css`), однако все файлы мне не требуются. На фотографии ниже видно, что подгружено 4 файла (2 раза загружен гугл-шрифт + `main.css` + `about.css`), а должно быть 2 файла (гугл-шрифт + `main.css`).

В интернете написано что-то про `bundle-action`, но я не могу понять как эту проблему решить.

#### Пример кода:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Head from "./components/Head";
import Main from './components/Main';
import About from './components/About';

class App extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Head/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact>
                        <Main/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/about">
                        <About/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

#### Main.js и About.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../css/main.css';

class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           //некоторый код
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../css/about.css';

class About extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           //некоторый код
        );
    }
}


export default About;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Edit interesting-tree-j38tk]

Comment: А не проще использовать CSS модули? Те же css файлы, но классам добавляются приставки, которые видны только в локально области видимости.

Comment: @Александр типо `import style as '../css/about.css'` + `className={style.NAME}`?

Comment: Типо, да https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-react-2ca5c0c7464b почитайте про 3-й метод

Comment: @Александр не помогло. CSS сам подгружается нормально. Тут проблем нет. Проблема в том,  что подгружается несколько

Comment: Значит вы что-то делаете не так, потому-что логика которую вы написали, это точно не будет работать. Потому-что когда билдите ваш проект css файлы складываются в один bundle.css а как ему понять какие классы и на какой странице применять? Или вы планируете develop версию выкладывать на домен?

Comment: @Александр добавил ссылку на пример проекта (в конце вопросы)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/pedantic-silence-gjqn1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: У меня CSS файл на 1200 строк..., а файл этот генирируется с помощью CSS-препроцессора - SCSS. Файл `main.scss` содержит только `@import`  на файлы  с помощью, который собран из 23-25 различных отдельных файлов (привет БЭМу... блин).

Comment: @Александр Ваш пример хороший, не спорю... Но вот как подпилить его под подгрузку внешних CSS-файлов

Comment: Можно попробовать посмотреть документацию по webpack-config, но мало вероятно, если это импорты в css. Ну если дэдлайн скоро, тогда просто через js добавлять теги <Link> в head c href="путь со стилем", стоит учитывать, что билдиться это будет ужасно, если мой lead такое увидел бы в коде, тем более на React, руки бы мне точно сломали.

Comment: @Александр  улучшил ответ ваш

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучшим решением в данном случае будет использование [CSS-modules].[1](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

Данная технология позволяет Вам использовать **единый css-файл**, что позволяет избавиться от импорта нескольких файлов (однако вы можете импортировать несколько в один компонент, но лучше этого не делать).

#### Что надо сделать:

1. Создать `CSS-файл` с именем оканчивающееся на `.module.css`
   Пример: `main-page.module.css`, а не просто `main-page.css`
2. Импортировать файл в ваш `JS-файл` как `import styles from '/путь/к/файлу/ИМЯ.module.css'`
3. Добавлять `styles` внутрь html-кода с указанием названия класса из вашего файла
   Пример:
   Вызов одного класса: `<div className={styles.dish}> ... </div>`
   Вызов нескольких классов: `<h2 className={[styles.text, styles.text_headerMedium, styles.text_italic].join(" ")}>Имя</h2>`
   Вызов нескольких классов (2 Вариант): `` <div className={`${styles.description} ${styles.yellow}\`}> ``
4. Так как вы используете БЭМ, надо учесть, что имена должны писаться в стиле `camelCase`: `blockName__elemName_modName_modVal`

---

#### Полезные ссылки:

[YouTube - HOW TO USE CSS MODULES WITH CREATE-REACT-APP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Udf951dyTdU)
[БЭМ - Соглашение по именованию](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/)
[SO - using css modules how do I define more than one style name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949469/using-css-modules-how-do-i-define-more-than-one-style-name)